# Removing elements without id from a jQuery selection?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors

**How can i remove elements without `id` property from the collection (not from the DOM itself) on which the plugin was invoked?**

```
<span id="id737293" class="attach"></span>
<div class="attach"></span>
```

jQuery invocation and plugin:

```
$('.attach').attach();

(function($) {

    $.fn.attach = function(options) {
       // Remove elements (without id) on which the plugin was invoked
       var valid = ???;

       // Loop each valid element (with id attribute) and process
       valid.each(function() {
       });

       return this; // Maintain chainability
    };

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [.filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to remove elements without an ID.

```
(function($) {

    $.fn.attach = function(options) {
       // Remove elements (without id) on which the plugin was invoked
       var valid = this.filter(function() { return !!this.id; });

       // Loop each valid element (with id attribute) and process
       valid.each(function() {               
       });

       return this; // Maintain chainability
    };

})(jQuery);

$('.attach').attach();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5Kn9W/2/

or `var valid = this.not(':not([id])');` - http://jsfiddle.net/5Kn9W/1/

Comment: Brilliant. as i understand this will only filter the selection without affecting DOM or chainability, am i right?

Comment: @Gremo Yes, only the `valid` variable will contain the filtered list of elements.

Comment: That's fine, but filter function should return valid elements (thus returning this.id)... as jsfiddle shows invalid element in red ;)

Comment: Why use filter when you can do it with a selector? Seems silly to use a function here.

Comment: Because inside the plugin you don't have any control over the selector used to call the plugin.

Answer (score 1):

```
 if(!$(elem).prop("id")){
   $(this).remove()
}
```

Comment: Will this break chainability? I mean i'd like to loop each valid element of the selection, but without removing the element from the DOM itself.

Comment: you need only check if(!$("some element").prop("id")){ than do something  }

Answer (score 1):

```
var elementsWithClassAttachAndHasId = jQuery(".attach:has([id])");
var elementsWithClassAttachAndNoId = jQuery(".attach:not([id])");
```

Comment: I suppose this will remove from the collection AND the DOM, right?

Comment: Looks like the question was edited since it, I will edit my answer to match now.